# Libgdx: SpriteBatch.draw spriteVertecies wierd UV coords behavior

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I'm trying to display a simple textured trapezoid (a road in perspective). For this I'm using [SpriteBatch.draw](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html#draw-com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture-float:A-int-int-) with vertexes array as a parameter. But the result is unexpected.

What I expected:
[image]

What I got:
[image]

What exactly gone wrong? Or maybe I'm using the wrong method?

Here is the code:

```
@Override
public void create () {
    texture = new Texture("road.jpg");

    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();

    float color = Color.toFloatBits(255, 255, 255, 255);

    verts = new float[]{
            0,                              0,      color, 0, 0,
            Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2-100,  300,    color, 0, 1,
            Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2+100,  300,    color, 1, 1,
            Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),        0,      color, 1, 0,
    };

    shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0.5f, 1f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
    shapeRenderer.rect(0, 0, 640, 300);
    shapeRenderer.end();

    spriteBatch.begin();
    spriteBatch.draw(texture, verts, 0, verts.length);
    spriteBatch.end();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html)

> `draw(Texture texture, float[] spriteVertices, int offset, int count)`
>
> Draws a rectangle using the given vertices.

LibGDX draws these rectangles as two triangles, so it splits the texture. The problem is that these triangles in rectangle are the same size, but in trapezoid they are not, so they become distorted.

Solution would be to use projection or mesh.

[image: Image showing real UV mapping]
[image: Texture UV mapping]